# Filling an empty object array with a full one randomly in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, random

So lets say i have two object arrays...

```
    Test[] Filled = new Test[5]; //copied from
    Test[] Empty = new Test[5]; // pasted to

    //they contain 3 different variables aswell
```

How would you do it if you would copy (not remove) 5 random objects into random positions. From Filled to Empty. There can be duplicates just as long as its randomly done.

Comment: Ok, I see the arrays, but what about what you've tried so far in order to copy your objects?

Comment: Iterating the full array; generate a random number between 0 - 4 inclusive; this number will be the index into the target array; If that array position already has something in it, try again w/ a new random number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution.

```
        Test[] Filled = new Test[5]; 
        Test[] Empty = new Test[5]; 

        //insert some data to Filled array

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 4);

        for (int i = 0; i < Empty.Length; i++)
        {
            Empty[i] = Filled[randomNumber];
            randomNumber = random.Next(0, 4);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean shuffling with the possiblity of duplicates. Try something like:

```
var random = new Random();
var randomized = new Test[Filled.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < Filled.Length; i++)
{
    randomized[i] = Filled[random.Next(Filled.Length)];
}
```